# How to get array values in a query from an array variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a model like this

```
function show_city_n_area_from_id($data){ // $data is an array of ids
    $this->db->select('column1');
    $this->db->from('table');
    $this->db->where('id', $data);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $query_result = $query_array();
    return $query_result;
}
```

I am trying to extract all the values from 'column1' in the form of an array from '$data' which is an array of several ids.

Thanks in advance.

I get error:

> Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause' SELECT `column1` FROM `table` WHERE `id` = `Array`

Comment: And what is not working?

Comment: I get error `Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause' SELECT `column1` FROM `table` WHERE `id` = `Array``

Comment: If its associative array print_r($data) and share the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your comments `$data` is an array of ids so you need to use `where_in` like:

```
$this->db->where_in('id', $data);
```

**Modified code**:

```
function show_city_n_area_from_id($data){ 
   $this->db->select('column1'); 
   $this->db->from('table'); 
   $this->db->where_in('id', $data); 
   $query = $this->db->get(); 
   $query_result = $query_array(); 
   return $query_result; 
}
```

You can also explore the [CI User Guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data)

**UPDATE 1:**

As per your comments you have ids inside the object so you can convert it into an array as:

```
$dbIDS = array();
foreach($data['ids'] as $value){
    $dbIDS[] = $value->vbc_item_id;
}
```

Now you can use `$dbIDS` in `where_in`

Comment: I get 2 errors now .. "Array to string conversion" & SELECT `column1` FROM `table` WHERE `id` IN('My Listings', Array, Array, Array)..

Comment: @codeigniter_learner Its associative array??? Print_r($data) and share the result

Comment: @codeigniter_learner array should be $data['My Listings']

Comment: I am sorry my bad.. I had couple of data query on controller.. Now if I `print_r($data['ids']);` in model I get "Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [vbc_item_id] => 44 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [vbc_item_id] => 45 ) )"

Comment: @codeigniter_learner working on it.

Comment: Thanks so much.. It works now.. LITTLE UPDATE: "It worked after changing`$query_array()` to `$query->result()`" because I got an error with that "Undefined variable: query_array" & "Function name must be a string".. But that solved my problem

Comment: Cool @codeigniter_learner happy coding friend

Comment: @devpro codeigniter doc's have now moved to here http://www.codeigniter.com/docs

Comment: @wolfgang1983: yes u r right, early morning i open few url from google, it returns me bad url..